# How to perform this average count per hour calculation in SQL?

Tags: sql, select, average, amazon-athena

A simplified version of my table looks like this:

| id | hour |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 2 | 14 |

The `hour` column means 3am, 4am, 12pm etc. What I'd like to be able to do (working in Amazon Athena) is to calculate the average number of times an `id` occurs per hour. So for `id` 1, I'd have 3 occurrences at 3am and 1 at 4am, making my average calculation `(3+1)/2 = 2 per hour`. My combination of `count` and `group by` operators are not getting the job done at the moment.

Output I want:

| id | average per hour |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1.5 |

Comment: Please include the queries you actually tried, specify what was wrong with the output, and include sample output that you do want. [mre]

Comment: Why don't you count the hours where the occurences were 0? If an id appears at 1am, 3am and 5am, surely the average (from 1am to 5am, inclusive) is 0.6?

Comment: @MatBailie Just not needed for this task, only needed for the hours that are in the original table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the total count per id by the distinct count of hours:

```sql
SELECT   id, COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT hour)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much, it was just that little bit of logic on the first line that I was struggling with!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, which is longer bu more generalised, is to aggregate twice

```
SELECT
  id, AVG(occurences)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id, hour, COUNT(*) AS occurences
  FROM
    mytable
  GROUP BY
    id, hour
)
   AS rates
GROUP BY
  id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT hour,AVG(id_count) AS average_count_per_hour FROM (SELECT
hour,
id,
COUNT(*) AS id_count FROM
your_table GROUP BY
hour,
id) subquery GROUP BY hour ORDER BY hour;
```

Comment: The required output is "per id", you've given "per hour".

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**